# Creating validation/filter/error/other rules for selecting records in a look-up field

Tags: validation

Let's say I have a custom object called SALADS. SALADS has two field look-up relations to custom objects FRUITS and VEGETABLES. How would I go about creating a rule/error saying that, while creating a record for SALADS, if I selected "Apple" from the FRUITS look-up I couldn't select "Lettuce" from the VEGETABLES look-up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's an odd use case that may have a better solution, if you want to elaborate on the requirements.

Comment: Your answer worked well, but I was also wondering if it was possible to make it so that if I selected "Apple" and then proceeded to look-up a vegetable, only the applicable vegetables would be displayed in the look-up field instead of all of them. I was also thinking of turning the look-ups into pick lists via visual force, so only having the applicable records showing would be better.

Comment: You might be able to do that witha VLOOKUP on the ligation side. I have no idea about using VF to make a pick list of them, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your validation rule to compare the object names. Assuming your lookup fields are named `Fruit__c` and `Vegetable__c`, with name fields the default `Name`, your validation rule would look like:

`(Fruit__r.Name = "Apple") && ( Vegetable__r.Name = "Lettuce")`

The field names were found by:

1. Click Insert Field
2. Select `Salad >` in the first column
3. Select `Fruit >` in the second column
4. Select `Fruit Name` in the third column
5. Repeat for Vegetable

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember mark this as an answer and vote for it if you found it useful.

Comment: I had added another comment and will wait for its answer, but if it can't be done then I will mark this one as the answer! I don't have enough reputation to vote up yet, sorry!